# how do i reset select option dropdown when selecting a different field element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

html

```
<div class="row-fluid together">
    <div class="span3">
      <p>
        <label for="typeofmailerradio1" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofmailerradio1" name="typeofmailerradio" value="Postcards" />Postcards</label>
      </p>

      <div id="typeofpostcardmaileroptions" class="hide">

      <p>
      <label for="typeofpostcardmailerradio1" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofpostcardmailerradio1" name="typeofpostcardmailer" value="Postcard Sizes" />Postcard Sizes</label>
      </p>
      <div id="postcardsizeoptions" class="hide">
      <select name="postcardsize">
      <option value="">pick size</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <p>
      <label for="typeofpostcardmailerradio2" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofpostcardmailerradio2" name="typeofpostcardmailer" value="Custom Size" />Custom Size</label>
      </p>
      <div id="customsizeoption" class="hide">
      <input type="text" id="postcardcustomsize" name="postcardcustomsize" value="" />
      </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <label for="typeofmailerradio2" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofmailerradio2" name="typeofmailerradio" value="Snaps" />Snaps</label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>
        <label for="typeofmailerradio3" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofmailerradio3" name="typeofmailerradio" value="Specialty Mailers" />Specialty Mailers</label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <label for="typeofmailerradio4" class="radio"><input type="radio" id="typeofmailerradio4" name="typeofmailerradio" value="Mailers" />Mailers</label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js

```
//clear sub options if another main option is selected
$("input[name='typeofmailerradio']").change(function(){
$("input[name='typeofpostcardmailer']").prop('checked', false);
$('#postcardsizeoptions').hide("fast");
$('#postcardsize').find('option:first').attr('selected',true);
});

//show or hide options of postcards
$("input[name='typeofmailerradio']").click(function() {
if(this.value == 'Postcards') {
    $('#typeofpostcardmaileroptions').show("fast");
}
else {
    $('#typeofpostcardmaileroptions').hide("fast");
}
});

//show or hide post card sizes dropdown box
$("input[name='typeofpostcardmailer']").click(function() {
if(this.value == 'Postcard Sizes') {
    $('#postcardsizeoptions').show("fast");
    $('#customsizeoption').hide("fast");
}
else {
    //$('#postcardsize').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $('#postcardsize').find('option:first').attr('selected',true);
    $('#postcardsizeoptions').hide("fast");
    $('#customsizeoption').show("fast");
    //$('#typeofpostcardmailerradio2').change(function(){
        //$('#postcardsize').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        //$('#postcardsize').val(     $('#postcardsize').prop('defaultSelected') );
    //}
}
//if(this.value == 'Custom Size') {
    //$('#postcardsize').val( $('#postcardsize').prop('defaultSelected') );
    //$('#postcardsize').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    //var mypostcardsizeselect = $("select#postcardsize");
    //mypostcardsizeselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    //mypostcardsizeselect.selectmenu("refresh");
//}
});

//reset postcard size dropdown if custom picked
//$('#typeofpostcardmailerradio2').change(function(){
//  $('#postcardsize').prop('selectedIndex',0);
//}
```

css

```
.hide {display: none}
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Mk24U/

having trouble getting the dropdown to reset when selecting other parts of the form.  things i have tried are all the commented out lines in the js area.

clicking postcards opens new form elements

clicking postcard sizes opens dropdown element

clicking custom size closes dropdown and opens a text field

clicking the other main radio buttons like snap, specialty, and mailers, closes all the sub options under postcards and also resets the postcard sizes and custom size radio buttons.

when selecting an dropdown option other than "pick size", then selecting custom size, i want the dropdown option to reset to pick size.

also when selecting snap, specialty mailer, or mailers, i want the dropdown to reset to pick size.

all the things i tried, i tried putting insider the if/else, outside the if/else, and outside the function in it's own function.

nothing is working.

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, i.e. what does "reset" mean in this case?

Comment: say you get to the dropdown and select "2". then click the custom radio and the dropdown box hides, but the value is still "2".  i want whatever was selected to be "reset" and now the new selection is "pick size".

Comment: @leoarce You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/Mk24U/2/

Comment: yes this worked, thanks. $('#postcardsizeoptions').find('select').val('0');

Answer (score 1):

well, easiest will be adding a class to other main radio buttons like snap, specialty, and mailers to say `someClass` and calling the click event of it , when clicked change the value of select to empty which is pick size

try this

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
  if(this.checked){
     $('select[name="postcardsize"]').val("");
  }
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk24U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your selector

replace

```
 $('#postcardsize').find('option:first').attr('selected',true);
```

with

```
 $('select[name=postcardsize]').find('option:first').attr('selected',true);
```

it should work